# How to acquire image stream from RTSP camera through HTTP?

Tags: delphi, http, delphi-xe2, rtsp, indy

I was wondering if I can use an HTTP protocol to acquire an image stream from an RTSP camera? I am currently using VLC Media ActiveX Plugin to connect to and view the RTSP stream, but I would like to eliminate the ActiveX control and move to a more raw level of image acquisition. I recall seeing somewhere that it's possible to get these images using HTTP. I'd like to use Indy `TIdHTTP` component to connect to the camera and acquire the image. I'm also assuming this would need some sort of speed control, such as a delay in-between requests. However, it's also my understanding that these RTSP cameras have pre-defined frame rates, which using the standard RTSP protocol are supposed to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

many cameras will allow you to grab screenshots with a URL that might look like:

```
http://user:password@camera/snapshot.jpg
```

for a proper stream, you would need to use RTSP (there are Delphi RTSP clients), tunnelling over HTTP if your device supports the [application/x-rtsp-tunnelled](https://developer.apple.com/quicktime/icefloe/dispatch028.html) content type, or another stream your device supports.